# AngularJS - ngRoute can't find file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm trying to display some data from JSON file but I can't use ngRoute properly.
For the record, I'm running the files locally using CORS plugin for Chrome.
When I'm trying to access ~/project/13 (where 13 is an ID) the browser return "File not found". There's no errors in the console either.

Here's the code: 
**hello.js**

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
                    $routeProvider
                    .when('/project/:projectId',{
                    controller:'GetProjectCtrl',
                    templateUrl:'project.html'
                })
});  
myApp.controller('GetProjectCtrl', ['$routeParams','$scope','$http', function($routeParams,$scope,$http){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/project/'+$routeParams.projectId).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.project = data;
    });
    console.log($routeParams.projectId);
}]);
```

**project.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="hello.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div id="wrapper">

    <header>
        <div class="header-left">
            <h1>Sonar Monitoring Tool</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <table ng-controller="GetProjectCtrl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>URL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{project.id}}</td>
            <td>{{project.name}}</td>
            <td>{{project.url}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here?

**Later edit**

Apparently there is an error which is:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/******/Desktop/Angular/project/13
```

Comment: Try changing your templateUrl to `appFolder/subFolder/project.html´, if that's you folder structure. Or did you put `template.html` in you're root folder directly?

Comment: @aup tried that, didn't worked.

Comment: @alexey this is the error I'm getting. I didn't see it until now: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/******/Desktop/Angular/project/13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run youre site under a server. you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server a simple starters http server with zero configuration ,install using NPM.